# Python class referencing

Tags: python, class

I tried to create two objects that both have their own inventories.
As far as I'm concerned I successfully managed to create two different objects called **my_bag** and **toms_bag**
This is the code I used

```
class bag(object):
   def inventory_add(self, item):
      self.inventory.append(item)

   inventory = []

bags = []   #List of all bags   

#Create bags
my_bag = bag()
my_bag.inventory_add("pencil")
bags.append(my_bag)

toms_bag = bag()
toms_bag.inventory_add("book")
bags.append(toms_bag)

for bag in bags:    #Print inventories
   print(bag, bag.inventory)
```

This is the result I get.

```
<__main__.bag object at 0x004D0830> ['pencil', 'book']
<__main__.bag object at 0x004D0790> ['pencil', 'book']
```

So why are the items added to both of their inventories? Are they even different objects now?

Comment: ``inventory`` is a class variable, not an instance variable, thus all instances of this class share the same variable.

Comment: With `inventory = []`, you are declaring a variable in the class itself, no in objects created from this class, which means the variable `inventory` will be common to all your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks like you're coming from C#, Java, C++, or some other more strictly OOP language. The way to do what you want in Python is to initialize the inventory array in the class constructor:

```
class bag(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []

    def inventory_add(self, item):
       self.inventory.append(item)
```